# Table expands on "tr:before"

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to achieve a sort of selection effect on a table that I'm currently working on. I want to do this by adding a class to the table row that the user clicks. The class that gets added to the row will add a small circle to the left of the row. However, as I'm adding the class to the row, the table (or the row) seems to expand a few pixels. I can't figure out why.

Some example code to illustrate my problem:

```js
document.querySelector('tr').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
    this.classList.add('clicked');
    return;
  }

  this.classList.remove('clicked');
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
.clicked:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Longer text..</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: the `:before` and `:after` elements are added into the selected element, before its content and after its content, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helped me solve the problem. Seems :before actually "creates" a new table cell. Had to add the :before to the first `<td>` in my code instead of the `<tr>`.

[Is it possible to use pseudo-elements (:after, :before) inside a table row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588674/is-it-possible-to-user-pseudo-element-after-before-on-table-row-safely)

Answer (score 1):

You could add your `clicked:before` element and set it's `opacity` to `0` and then on the `click event` add another class to actually show the element.

```js
document.querySelector('tr').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!this.classList.contains('show-clicked')) {
    this.classList.add('show-clicked');
    return;
  }

  this.classList.remove('show-clicked');
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

tr {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clicked:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show-clicked:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="clicked">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Four</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Longer text..</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a trick. I hope it works as what you want

```js
document.querySelector('tr').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (!this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
    this.classList.add('clicked');
    return;
  }

  this.classList.remove('clicked');
});
```

```css
table {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
.show-me {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.show-me span {
  display: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
.clicked .show-me span {
   display: block; 
}
```

```html
   
<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="show-me">
          <span></span>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Longer text..</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Four</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's kind of what I want, but I actually want the "dot" to display outside the table. Seems the :before actually adds a new table cell. I solved this by adding the :before to the first <td> instead of the <tr>

Comment: I think DavidDomain's answer is the best solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

You could use the css [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property and an extra class. This way any effect that is caused by `::before` will be in the rendering but just not visible.

> Summary The visibility property can be used to hide an element while
>   leaving the space where it would have been. It can also hide rows or
>   columns of a table.

```js
document.querySelector('tr').addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.classList.toggle('visible');
});
```

```css
table {
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 5rem auto;
}
.clicked::before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.visible::before {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="clicked">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Four</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Longer text..</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Four</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```