# vue.js ::before in Rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am creating a table of full order details.  Below is the code.  The problem is 
the grid is shifted in the table body. Does anybody know how the ::before is rendered?  How do I stop this or adjust the HTML?

**CodeSnippet**

[image: CodeSnippet]

**Display**

[image: Display]

**Rendered HTML**

[image: Rendered HTML]

It won't let me post the actual pictures, but just links to them.

Comment: Please post your actual code, not images of code.

Comment: Definitely can't tell what you're trying to do without seeing the CSS, but  browser rendering of pseudo-elements in tables has a lot of issues so that's likely the cause.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588674/is-it-possible-to-user-pseudo-element-after-before-on-table-row-safely

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
tr.row::before{
  content: none;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).